# preg_replace is replacing $ signs

Tags: php, regex

I have the following piece of code which replaces "template markers" such as %POST_TITLE% with the contents of a variable called $post_title.

```
function replaceTags( $template, $newtext ) {
    $template = preg_replace( '/%MYTAG%/', $newtext, $template );
    return $template;
}
```

The issue is that when $post_full has a '$' in it, the returned result has this removed. For example:

```
$template = "Replace this: %MYTAG";
$newtext = "I earn $1,000,000 a year";

print replaceTags( $template, $newtext );

// RESULT
Replace this: I earn ,000,000 a year";
```

I know this has something to do with not properly escaping the $1 in the $newtext. I have tried using preg_quote() but it doesn't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [preg_replace manual](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), preg_replace() treats this (`$1`) as **[backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)**.
(and not a "<strike>callback syntax</strike>" as mentionned in the comments of the preg_replace manual page.
Thank you [Jan Goyvaerts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33358/jan-goyvaerts)).

```
$newtext = preg_replace("!" . '\x24' . "!" , '\\\$' , $newtext );
```

should take care of your '$' sign

Comment: For accuracy, I've decided to give this the "answer" tick, although derobert's answer is also quite accurate. BTW, what is the "!" . '\x24' . "!" bit?

Comment: I am not sure actually! I suppose it forces the regex to match only '$' sign (which is 24 in hexadecimal ASCII code), but I am not familiar with that "!\x24!" regex...

Comment: Your solution is correct, but your terminology is wrong.  $1 is a backreference, not a callback.

Answer (score 6):

Ummm, since you aren't actually using a regexp there, why not just use `str_replace`? It'll be faster and you won't have weird issues like this.

Comment: Good point. It's code that came with a wordpress plugin so I never even thought of changing it.